# How PySide6 paintEvent function for a PushButton works?

Tags: python, qt, pyside6, pyqt6, enaml

A long time ago, I wanted to make a logo appear on top of the text in a QPushButton stacked on top of each other, but I couldn't find anyway

- I read some stylesheets (couldn't find a single doc to read it all about all styles I can apply to a button)
- tried the setLayoutDirection (RightToLeft and LeftToRight were there, but no UpToDown direction)
- In my (I wish) last attempt I tried to inherit a QAbstractButton (I didn't find QAbstractPushButton, so I guess QAbstractButton is the answer) and change its paintEvent/paintEngine to draw an image or maybe add a vbox inside it as a layout to draw to components, but I can't find anything in python (specially PySide) which has an example in any possible way close to that. The best thing I found was the analogue clock example which was not very helpful because it was trying to work a QWidget and not a QAbstractButton and I want to keep the feel of a Native looking button.

I like my final product to be something like this.

[image: Enaml based example image]

[source of the implemention of that](https://github.com/nucleic/enaml/blob/main/enaml/widgets/tool_bar.py#L58)

Python Enaml toolkit supported this feature out of the box (in one of its widgets), and I know it is QT based, so I really wish to know how it is possible?

p.s.: Also, is there a market for qt widgets? e.g.: a plugin system. Because rewriting an android like switch doesn't seem like the correct thing that I should do! even a good tutorial or doc would be appreicated (excluding [official doc](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/PySide6))

Comment: Use [QToolButton](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtoolbutton.html) and [`setToolButtonStyle()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtoolbutton.html#toolButtonStyle-prop) with `Qt.ToolButtonTextUnderIcon`.

Comment: Note that if you want a *tool bar*, you should use [QToolBar()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtoolbar.html) and add [QActions](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qaction.html) to it (which is fundamentally what the linked code does). Similarly as above, you must use `setToolButtonStyle()` on that tool bar, which will use the given button style as default for all actions.

Comment: @musicamante Right now I gave it a try, I couldn't make QToolbutton to work, but adding as action worked, although the size of icon is smaller and when I set min height for toolbar didn't help it (the action size kept constent and empty region expanded around it)

Comment: @musicamante My process was I made a QToolButton, and addwidget it to QToolbar, which resulted to it not showing up, I had some issues similar to it with VBox in widget (which is setLayout and not addWidget) if I'm making an idiot mistake like that please mention me

Comment: Please carefully read the *whole* documentation about QToolBar.

Comment: I fixed it, problem was in third party (qt_material) styling package which probably had some specific stylesheets specified height of toolbox. Fixed by addAction (still QToolButton didn't work for me). Thanks for participation, You can submit your comment, so I can accept it as answer

Comment: As said above and explained in the documentation, you shall not need to add a QToolButton to QToolBar (which might also create styling/layout issues and unavailability of the extension button if the toolbar is not set on a main window), but add a QAction, which will properly follow the style inheritance of QToolBar *and* QToolButton according to the style rules, and follow the predefined behavior. When you add a QAction, QToolBar creates its own QToolButtons *internally*, so you don't need to do that.

Answer (score 0):

It is easier than you think, you can use QToolButton() like this:

```
import sys

from PySide6.QtCore import Qt, QSize
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QVBoxLayout,QStyle, QWidget, 
QToolButton

class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Window, self).__init__(parent)
        
        button = QToolButton()
       
        # here you choose the position of the icon and its text
        button.setToolButtonStyle(
        Qt.ToolButtonStyle.ToolButtonTextUnderIcon)
    
        # here I just use built-in icon by PySide6 for this example
        name = 'SP_DialogSaveButton'
        pixmapi = getattr(QStyle, name)
        icon = self.style().standardIcon(pixmapi)
        
        # here we set text and icon of size 32x32 to the button 
        button.setIcon(icon)
        button.setText("Sample text")
        button.setIconSize(QSize(32, 32))
        
        # finally we add our button to the layout
        lay = QVBoxLayout(self)
        lay.addWidget(button, alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)

if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = Window()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

[image]

Comment: I have one problem with this, how to add it to a QToolBar. Because no matter what I tried, I couldn't get the QToolButton into the Toolbar and only adding action to it (and letting it implicitly creating it for me) worked, I guess that's my only problem with your answer (and overall, my only remaining problem)